# Django - how to dynamically generate a menu based on use privs

Tags: django, django-templates

Does anyone know a good way to solve this other problem I have. My site shows menus based on a users privs. I have a function that returns the privs as a dictionary as below:

```
return {"manage_entries":True, "manage_members":False, 
   "manage_something_else":True}
```

I passed in each priv to my base template that includes the navigation bar and use simple `{% if priv %}` to decide if I am going to show the menu item or not. It works fine except...

I need to pass the privs in the context of every view as they all include the base.html template and thus menu. There are lots of views so this is stupid. There must be a better way!

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to write a simple [custom template context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). This is as simple as a function that accepts an instance of `HttpRequest` and returns a dictionary. In your case the dictionary can contain a list of the privileges for the current user.

For e.g.

```
# This is our processor. 
def append_privileges(request):
    privileges = get_privs(request.user)
    return dict(privileges = privileges)
```

Where `get_privs` is the method that will return the dictionary of privileges as you have indicated in your question.

Now add this processor to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting in your `settings.py`. Generally this variable is not present in settings. When you add it, make sure that you *copy* the [existing default](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#template-context-processors) and *then* append to it. For e.g.

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # copied from docs.
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",

    # appended custom value
    "app.utils.append_privileges",
)
```

Finally in your base template expect the `privileges` variable.

```
# I've added a pprint to test. You'll obviously need to do more. 
{{ privileges|pprint }}
```

This will make sure that all your views will automatically return a context with a correct `privileges` variable.

Comment: Thanks so much Manoj, that seems perfect! I really appreciate you putting your time into saving mine! Stackoverflow is an amazing tool for developers.

Comment: @Rich: glad to help. Pay it forward :)

Answer (score 3):

Adding custom context processor is unnecesary, since processor 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' appends priveleges into the context :)

And you can do things like:

```
{% if perms.foo %}
    <p>You have permission to do something in the foo app.</p>
{% if perms.foo.can_vote %}
    <p>You can vote!</p>
{% endif %}
{% if perms.foo.can_drive %}
    <p>You can drive!</p>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
   <p>You don't have permission to do anything in the foo app.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: For those looking for references, this method mentioned by @jb has more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions), [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication).